# Gooey effect messed up after transition ends

Tags: jquery, css, svg-filters

I'm trying to create a kind of radio button with the gooey effect.
The effect looks well while the transition happens, but as soon as the transition ends, the effect is messed up (the colors do not blend well and the edges glow).

I've been trying to figure out what's the problem, without success.

Video: https://vimeo.com/248225026

Here is the code:

```js
$('.register-option').click(function() {
  $('.register-option').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(158, 158, 158);
}

.register-choose {
  -webkit-filter: url(#goo);
  filter: url(#goo);
}

.register-choose .register-option {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.register-choose .register-option.selected {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.register-choose .register-option:first-of-type.selected {
  background-color: rgb(0, 181, 255);
}

.register-choose .register-option:last-of-type.selected {
  background-color: rgb(255, 118, 217);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="register-choose">
                <span class="register-option selected">Male</span>
<span class="register-option">Female</span>
</span>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
   <filter id="goo">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
    <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 16 -6" result="goo" />
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop" />
   </filter>
  </defs>
 </svg>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What browser do you see the problem in? Chrome doesn't look like the video for me.

Comment: Reducing `stdDeviation` from 10 to around 5 prevents the 'glow' top and bottom borders in Firefox.

Comment: dom_ahdigital in Chrome. Also in Chrome Mobile. Reducing stdDeviation makes the effect weaker, isn't there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is a magical incantation that seems to solve the Firefox visual bug. I have no idea why it works, but it seems to kick the right part of the Firefox filter code.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <defs>
            <filter id="goo" >
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
                <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 16 -6"/>

    <feComponentTransfer result="goo">
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 .2 .4 .6 1 1"/>
     </feComponentTransfer>
            <<feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Comment: It's still looking the same in Chrome and even in Firefox.

Comment: This works for me on latest Chrome/FF on Windows. Can you add your browser versions and OS?

Comment: Chrome 63, Windows 10

Comment: Works for me. You may have some Chrome flags enabled, or these may be due to a buggy GPU/driver. Try it on another PC.